# Buscar columnas con style display none y removerlas

Tags: jquery

Tengo una tabla así:

```
<table id="mi_tabla">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th style="display: none;"></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td style="display: none;"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td style="display: none;"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

y quiero remover esas columnas que tienen display none, como puedo hacerlo?

Gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar un selector jQuery que busque los elementos con el estilo `display: none`.  Si inspeccionas la tabla, veras que los elementos han sido removidos:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var th = $("#mi_tabla").find("tr th[style='display: none;']").remove();
  $("#mi_tabla").find("tr td[style='display: none;']").remove();
  $("#append").on("click", function() {
    $("#mi_tabla").find("th:first").after(th);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="mi_tabla">
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th style="display: none;">2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td style="display: none;">2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td style="display: none;">2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="append">Pegar</button>
```

Comment: Esta super pero ya tengo otra duda, al removerlos como puedo restablecer la tabla luego??

Comment: Si quieres removerlos momentaneamente, debes de guardarlos en una variable y utilizar `detach()` en lugar de `remove()`

Comment: Y de casualidad podrías explicarme como?

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta con un ejemplo de como restaurar el `th`

Answer (score 2):

En una sola linea podes hacerlo con [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp)

En este ejemplo que te dejo selecciono todos los elementos que tengan "display none" y luego los remuevo.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mi_tabla [style*='display: none']").remove()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="mi_tabla">
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th style="display: none;">2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td style="display: none;">2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td style="display: none;">2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```